# Create lock screen media control buttons

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, lockscreen, mediacontroller

I am developing a media player for android. As from API 21 Google has deprecated the use of `RemoteControlClient` in favor of `MediaStyle` notifications and `MediaController`. But the new functionality hasn't been added to the support library. So if I want my app to be compatible with older OS versions, I have to do someting like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLIPOP) {
  // Use MediaController
} else {
  // Use `RemoteControlClient`
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to accomplish this? The idea to support two different controller APIs is not so good (in my opinion).

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the AppCompat Support Library Revision 22.
It has new `MediaSessionCompat` & other support stuff.

For more details.

Check the links below:

[Media Session Compat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.html)

[Media Controller Compat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaControllerCompat.html)

Comment: I know about them... now :) In the time I asked the question, there were no such classes... Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: @KirilAleksandrov
I'm glad, btw do the lockscreen control work on Pre-Lollipop?